# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 flutter

Tags: ios, google-maps, flutter, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I'm working in an app flutter. Android working fine but in ios no. I need some help to run this on ios mobile. I'm using lib: **google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.27+3** and **firebase_ml_vision: ^0.9.3+8**. Xcode 11.4.1 and Mac os Catalina 10.15.4. Someone knows how to solve this. I didn't found yet.

```
flutter doctor
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale en-BR)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.45.0)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Log Error bellow:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSPolyline", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapPolylineController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRVisionOnDeviceImageLabelerOptions", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_ml_vision(ImageLabeler.o)
  "_FIRFaceLandmarkTypeLeftEar", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_FIRFaceLandmarkTypeMouthLeft", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_FIRFaceLandmarkTypeRightCheek", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_FIRFaceLandmarkTypeNoseBase", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_FIRFaceLandmarkTypeRightEye", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMarker", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapMarkerController.o)
  "_FIRFaceLandmarkTypeMouthRight", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_FIRFaceContourTypeLeftEye", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_FIRFaceContourTypeRightEye", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_FIRFaceContourTypeLowerLipTop", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSServices", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_FIRFaceContourTypeNoseBottom", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_FIRFaceLandmarkTypeLeftCheek", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_FIRFaceLandmarkTypeLeftEye", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMapStyle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapController.o)
  "_FIRFaceContourTypeRightEyebrowTop", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSPolygon", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapPolygonController.o)
  "_FIRFaceContourTypeUpperLipTop", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_FIRFaceContourTypeRightEyebrowBottom", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_FIRFaceContourTypeLeftEyebrowBottom", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_FIRFaceLandmarkTypeRightEar", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_FIRFaceContourTypeUpperLipBottom", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRVisionCloudImageLabelerOptions", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_ml_vision(ImageLabeler.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSCameraPosition", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapController.o)
  "_kGMSMinZoomLevel", referenced from:
      _InterpretMapOptions in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMapView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMutablePath", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapPolygonController.o)
      objc-class-ref in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapPolylineController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSCircle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapCircleController.o)
  "_FIRFaceLandmarkTypeMouthBottom", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSCoordinateBounds", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapController.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSCameraUpdate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapController.o)
  "_FIRFaceContourTypeLeftEyebrowTop", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRVision", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_ml_vision(FLTFirebaseMlVisionPlugin.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRVisionFaceDetectorOptions", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_kGMSMaxZoomLevel", referenced from:
      _InterpretMapOptions in google_maps_flutter(GoogleMapController.o)
  "_FIRFaceContourTypeAll", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_ml_vision(BarcodeDetector.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_ml_vision(FLTFirebaseMlVisionPlugin.o)
  "_FIRFaceContourTypeLowerLipBottom", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRVisionImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_ml_vision(FLTFirebaseMlVisionPlugin.o)
  "_FIRFaceContourTypeFace", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
  "_FIRFaceContourTypeNoseBridge", referenced from:
      ___39-[FaceDetector handleDetection:result:]_block_invoke in firebase_ml_vision(FaceDetector.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Do you have problems with physical device (iPhone)?

Comment: I had Objective-C Flutter project but tried to use plugin with Swift code. Recreating Flutter project with Swift solved the problem for me

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Probably the error is on some of the XCode project files, try:

1. Make a backup of your project.
2. Run this command

   flutter clean && \
   rm ios/Podfile ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock && \
   rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Runner.xcworkspace && \ 
   flutter run

[Reference](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41900#issuecomment-601599410)

Comment: I had to run separated but it works. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Perfect - worked a treat, thanks. For Mac I used...

`flutter clean; rm ios/Podfile ios/Podfile.lock pubspec.lock; rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Runner.xcworkspace; flutter run`

Comment: For me this answer didn't work. I am developing a Flutter plugin and in my case the solution is to add the line s.static_framework = true to the podspec file of my plugin. Hope this can help someone

Comment: perfect. it works

Comment: this didn't work for me too.

Comment: not working for me :(

Answer (score 4):

In mac with m1 chip I was not able to run my project in the simulator, instead I had to use a physical iPhone connected and it does not show errors, it runs fine.

Comment: Did you find any solution to run it on the simulator?

Answer (score 1):

The key part of this error might be "ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64". Seems related to the processor architecture, so try navigating to your project's folder in Terminal or in VS Code and use this command:

open iOS/Runner.xcworkspace

Make sure the iOS deployment target is correct. For some inexplicable reason, mine was set to iOS 11.0. I changed it to iOS 16.0 and it fixed the problem.

[Change under the PROJECT section to the appropriate iOS version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Y42.png)

[Change under the TARGETS section as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFmSQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is connectivity package you have used or not. Replaced with connectivity_plus plugin
and update your Flutter_ble_plus plugin .