# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Flutter run failed to build

Tags: xcode, flutter

When i try to `flutter run` i get this error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

Since there are quite a lot of warnings, I am only showing the error parts for now. I have tried a few solutions that get this type of error but still could not find the solution. This part seems to be the only reason I got an error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61805786/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-flutter

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem?