# I can't build my flutter app in Xcode 12.5 (Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I can build my app by `flutter run`, but I can't in Xcode for Archive.
Do anyone know how to fix this?

#### Error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_pb_encode", referenced from:
      _nano_two_pass_encoding in GoogleAppMeasurement(encoder_common.o)
  "_pb_encode_tag_for_field", referenced from:
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_app_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_app_property_encoder.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_audience in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_encoder.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_audience_leaf_filter_result in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_leaf_filter_result_encoder.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_client_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_client_property_encoder.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_custom_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_custom_property_encoder.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp_encoder.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_event in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_event_encoder.o)
      ...
  "_pb_read", referenced from:
      _apmpb_decode_repeated_app_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_app_property_decoder.o)
      _apmpb_decode_repeated_audience in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_decoder.o)
      _apmpb_decode_repeated_audience_leaf_filter_result in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_leaf_filter_result_decoder.o)
      _apmpb_decode_repeated_client_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_client_property_decoder.o)
      _apmpb_decode_repeated_custom_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_custom_property_decoder.o)
      _apmpb_decode_repeated_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp_decoder.o)
      _apmpb_decode_repeated_event in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_event_decoder.o)
      ...
  "_pb_decode", referenced from:
      _apmpb_decode_app_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_app_property_decoder.o)
      _apmpb_decode_audience in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_decoder.o)
      _apmpb_decode_audience_leaf_filter_result in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_leaf_filter_result_decoder.o)
      _apmpb_decode_client_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_client_property_decoder.o)
      _apmpb_decode_custom_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_custom_property_decoder.o)
      _apmpb_decode_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp_decoder.o)
      _apmpb_decode_event in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_event_decoder.o)
      ...
  "_pb_encode_string", referenced from:
      _nano_encode_string in GoogleAppMeasurement(encoder_common.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIROptions", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in firebase_core(FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.o)
  "_FIRFirestoreErrorDomain", referenced from:
      ___63-[FLTTransactionStreamHandler onListenWithArguments:eventSink:]_block_invoke in cloud_firestore(FLTTransactionStreamHandler.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRQuerySnapshot", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreWriter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRDocumentSnapshot", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreWriter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRFirestoreSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRFieldValue", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRDocumentChange", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreWriter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRFirestore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULSwizzler", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(UIViewController+APMScreenClassName.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRDocumentReference", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreWriter.o)
  "_kFIRFirestoreCacheSizeUnlimited", referenced from:
      -[FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader FIRFirestoreSettings] in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader.o)
  "_GULLogInfo", referenced from:
      ___44+[UIViewController(APMScreenClassName) load]_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement(UIViewController+APMScreenClassName.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRSnapshotMetadata", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreWriter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRGeoPoint", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader.o)
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreWriter.o)
  "_GULIsLoggableLevel", referenced from:
      -[APMMonitor isLoggableLevel:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMonitor.o)
  "_pb_encode_varint", referenced from:
      _nano_encode_repeated_uint64 in GoogleAppMeasurement(encoder_common.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRLoadBundleTaskProgress", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreWriter.o)
  "_GULLogError", referenced from:
      +[APMAnalytics startWithAppID:origin:options:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMAnalytics.o)
      -[APMUserDefaults synchronize] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMUserDefaults.o)
  "_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeNotModified", referenced from:
      -[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement.o)
      ___46-[APMMeasurement(URL) requestDeferredDeepLink]_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement+URL.o)
  "_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeNotFound", referenced from:
      -[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement.o)
  "_pb_ostream_from_buffer", referenced from:
      _nano_two_pass_encoding in GoogleAppMeasurement(encoder_common.o)
  "_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeCannotAcceptTraffic", referenced from:
      -[APMMeasurement networkUploadCompletionHandlerWithResponse:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement.o)
      -[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement.o)
      -[APMETaskManager handleFetchingExperimentsResponse:data:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMETaskManager.o)
  "_GULLogWarning", referenced from:
      +[APMMeasurement sharedInstance] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement.o)
      -[APMUserDefaults objectForKey:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMUserDefaults.o)
      -[APMUserDefaults setObject:forKey:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMUserDefaults.o)
      -[APMUserDefaults synchronize] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMUserDefaults.o)
      ___44+[UIViewController(APMScreenClassName) load]_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement(UIViewController+APMScreenClassName.o)
  "_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusNoContent", referenced from:
      -[APMMeasurement networkUploadCompletionHandlerWithResponse:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement.o)
      -[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement.o)
      -[APMETaskManager handleFetchingExperimentsResponse:data:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMETaskManager.o)
      ___46-[APMMeasurement(URL) requestDeferredDeepLink]_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement+URL.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULNetwork", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMAnalytics.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMAppDelegateInterceptor.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMETaskManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRTimestamp", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader.o)
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreWriter.o)
  "_pb_decode_varint", referenced from:
      _nano_decode_repeated_uint64 in GoogleAppMeasurement(decoder_common.o)
  "_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusCodeUnavailable", referenced from:
      -[APMMeasurement networkUploadCompletionHandlerWithResponse:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement.o)
      -[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement.o)
      -[APMETaskManager handleFetchingExperimentsResponse:data:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMETaskManager.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRFieldPath", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestoreReader.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULMutableDictionary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMEExperiment.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMEExperimentRequestBuilder.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMEManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMRemoteConfig.o)
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMESnapshot.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULAppEnvironmentUtil", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMEExperimentRequestBuilder.o)
  "_GULLogBasic", referenced from:
      -[APMASLLogger logMessage:logTag:messageCode:withLogLevel:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMASLLogger.o)
  "_kGULNetworkHTTPStatusOK", referenced from:
      -[APMMeasurement networkUploadCompletionHandlerWithResponse:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement.o)
      -[APMMeasurement networkRemoteConfigFetchCompletionHandler:data:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement.o)
      -[APMETaskManager handleFetchingExperimentsResponse:data:error:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMETaskManager.o)
      ___46-[APMMeasurement(URL) requestDeferredDeepLink]_block_invoke in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMeasurement+URL.o)
  "_pb_istream_from_buffer", referenced from:
      _apmpb_decode_app_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_app_property_decoder.o)
      _apmpb_decode_audience in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_decoder.o)
      _apmpb_decode_audience_leaf_filter_result in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_leaf_filter_result_decoder.o)
      _apmpb_decode_client_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_client_property_decoder.o)
      _apmpb_decode_custom_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_custom_property_decoder.o)
      _apmpb_decode_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp_decoder.o)
      _apmpb_decode_event in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_event_decoder.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GULAppDelegateSwizzler", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMAnalytics.o)
  "_GULSetLoggerLevel", referenced from:
      -[APMMonitor setDebugModeEnabled:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMonitor.o)
      -[APMMonitor setVerboseLoggingEnabled:] in GoogleAppMeasurement(APMMonitor.o)
  "_pb_encode_submessage", referenced from:
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_app_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_app_property_encoder.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_audience in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_encoder.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_audience_leaf_filter_result in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_audience_leaf_filter_result_encoder.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_client_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_client_property_encoder.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_custom_property in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_custom_property_encoder.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_dynamic_filter_result_timestamp_encoder.o)
      _apmpb_encode_repeated_event in GoogleAppMeasurement(apmpb_event_encoder.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in cloud_firestore(FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in firebase_core(FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in firebase_core(FLTFirebasePlugin.o)
      objc-class-ref in firebase_core(FLTFirebasePluginRegistry.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

#### What I did

- [Why linker link static libraries with errors? iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52536380/why-linker-link-static-libraries-with-errors-ios)
- [Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61805786/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-flutter)

and more (sorry, I can't remember).

Answer (score 0):

Delete `Podfile.lock`, Go to `ios` folder and run these commands,

1. `pod deintegrate`
2. `pod install`
3. `pod update`

Then run the project again and check.

Answer (score 0):

reconfigure the pod files by:

```
pod ios

pod cache clean --all

Pod clean

pod deintegrate

sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean

sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

arch -x86_64 pod repo update

arch -x86_64 pod install
```